# Algorithmic analysis of similarities across loglines?

Tags: algorithm, logging, machine-learning, analysis

I have logline that I'm trying to find patterns, or analyse for similarities in, across time.

Each logline can broken down into:

1. Timestamp
2. Module/function
3. Payload (i.e. the actual log message).

Are there any algorithmic approach for finding similarities in a set of loglines?

I know about things like Levenshtein distance for comparing strings, however, I was hoping for a more general approach that I could use to run across a logfile?

There probably isn't a one-size fits all solution to this (although if there is, please tell me!) - but pointers in the right direction, or places I can look for more info would be awesome.

EDIT - Some examples of types of loglines

```
11:30:00.028747923 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [BuyOrNot] session(server1) animal_type(cats) simpleprice(21643.5) complexprice(21641.9 - 21645.1) supercomplexprice(21641.9 - 21644.1)
11:30:00.028882087 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [BuyOrNot] session(server1) animal_type(cats) simpleprice(21643.2) complexprice(21643.2 - 21643.2) supercomplexprice(21643.2 - 21643.2)
11:30:00.039708519 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [BuyOrNot] session(server1) animal_type(cats) simpleprice(10465.8) complexprice(10465.8 - 10465.8) supercomplexprice(10465.8 - 10465.8)
11:30:00.039718896 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [BuyOrNot] session(server1) animal_type(cats) simpleprice(10466.5) complexprice(10465.9 - 10467.1) supercomplexprice(10465.9 - 10466.7)
11:30:00.040049452 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [BuyOrNot] session(server1) animal_type(cats) simpleprice(-0.184) complexprice(-0.184 - -0.184) supercomplexprice(-0.184 - -0.184)

11:30:00.704976265 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [SetChickenParameter] composite(wheatbag) leg(MARKET:388, 10456) legParams updated
11:30:00.704984746 [Info  ] [Skywalker] [OnCompositeLegVolatileParamsSetMessage] client(f1_ar_cmp_hk_tko_061), composite(wheatbag) composite leg(ID={Market="MARKET" Feedcode="386"} Identifier=10455) params(bidPrice=0 askPrice=0)
11:30:00.704992314 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [SetChickenParameter] composite(wheatbag) leg(MARKET:386, 10455) legParams updated
11:30:00.704995811 [Info  ] [Skywalker] [OnCompositeLegVolatileParamsSetMessage] client(f1_ar_cmp_hk_tko_061), composite(wheatbag) composite leg(ID={Market="MARKET" Feedcode="1171"} Identifier=16262) params(bidPrice=0 askPrice=0)
11:30:00.705002094 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [SetChickenParameter] composite(wheatbag) leg(MARKET:1171, 16262) legParams updated
11:30:00.705004666 [Info  ] [Skywalker] [OnCompositeLegVolatileParamsSetMessage] client(f1_ar_cmp_hk_tko_061), composite(wheatbag) composite leg(ID={Market="MARKET" Feedcode="883"} Identifier=10463) params(bidPrice=0 askPrice=0)
11:30:00.705010516 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [SetChickenParameter] composite(wheatbag) leg(MARKET:883, 10463) legParams updated
11:30:00.705012997 [Info  ] [Skywalker] [OnCompositeLegVolatileParamsSetMessage] client(f1_ar_cmp_hk_tko_061), composite(wheatbag) composite leg(ID={Market="MARKET" Feedcode="3968"} Identifier=10457) params(bidPrice=0 askPrice=0)
11:30:00.705018983 [Debug ] [Skywalker] [SetChickenParameter] composite(wheatbag) leg(MARKET:3968, 10457) legParams updated
```

I was thinking I could create some kind of dict of different regex to match the different types of logfiles - then find the variable points of each type - and use some kind of heuristic that matched how different/similar each point was?

Or is there a "smarter" way to tackle this?

Comment: The most important question here (which you need to answer before we can point you to any specific approach) is: how do you define similarity? It's probably a good idea to present some pairs of log lines you consider to be 'similar' and some that you think are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logline is already quite structured thing, so you can define different similarities criteria for different parts, e.g. timestamp field similarity can be how close two timestamps are or, just for example, the same time of the day, for module/function probably only exact equality would work, and comparison of payload greatly depends on your domain